# runtime error 217 at 005f57d7

Tags: delphi, runtime

Программа компилируется. Но когда проходишь отладчиком выдает такую ошибку:

```
runtime error 217 at 005f57d7
```

И указывает на эту часть кода:

```
function HandlerWndProc(WindowHandle: HWND; Message, wParam, lParam: Longint): Longint; stdcall;
var
  sr: PSyncRec;
  isDeferred: boolean;
  cancelled: boolean;
begin
  // wParam: 0 -- synchronized, 1 -- deferred
  if (Message <> CM_EXEC_FUNC)
    and (Message <> CM_DEFER_WITH_TIMEOUT)
    and (Message <> WM_TIMER) then
  begin
    result := DefWindowProc(WindowHandle, Message, wParam, lParam);
    exit;
  end;

  if Message = CM_DEFER_WITH_TIMEOUT then
  begin
    sr := PSyncRec(lParam);
    if SetTimer(WindowHandle, UINT(sr), wParam, nil) = 0 then
      raise Exception.Create('Unable to set timer for deferred run. GetLastError=' + IntToStr(GetLastError));
  end
  else
  begin
    if Message = WM_TIMER then
    begin
      sr := PSyncRec(wParam);
      KillTimer(WindowHandle, UINT(sr));
      isDeferred := true;
    end
    else
    begin
      sr := PSyncRec(lParam);
      isDeferred := wParam = 1;
    end;

    try
      try
        if isDeferred then
        begin
          EnterCriticalSection(CancelledSyncRunIDsLock);
          try
            cancelled := CancelledSyncRunIDs.Includes(integer(sr.ID));
            if cancelled then
              CancelledSyncRunIDs.Remove(integer(sr.ID));
          finally
            LeaveCriticalSection(CancelledSyncRunIDsLock);
          end;
        end
        else
          cancelled := false;
        if not cancelled and not SyncRunMachineryTerminated then
        case sr.Flags of
          0: TSyncProc(sr.Proc)();
          FF_HAS_PARAM: TSyncPtrProc(sr.Proc)(sr.Param);
          FF_HAS_STR_PARAM: TSyncStrProc(sr.Proc)(sr.Str);
          FF_HAS_RET: sr.Param := TSyncFuncReturningPtr(sr.Proc)();
          FF_HAS_STR_RET: sr.Str := TSyncFuncReturningStr(sr.Proc)();
          FF_HAS_PARAM or FF_HAS_RET: sr.Param := TSyncPtrFuncReturningPtr(sr.Proc)(sr.Param);
          FF_HAS_STR_PARAM or FF_HAS_RET: sr.Param := TSyncStrFuncReturningPtr(sr.Proc)(sr.Str);
          FF_HAS_PARAM or FF_HAS_STR_RET: sr.Str := TSyncPtrFuncReturningStr(sr.Proc)(sr.Param);
          FF_HAS_STR_PARAM or FF_HAS_STR_RET: sr.Str := TSyncStrFuncReturningStr(sr.Proc)(sr.Str);
          FF_NON_OBJ_PTR_PROC: TSyncPtrNonObjectProc(TMethod(sr.Proc).Code)(sr.Param);
          FF_VLIST_PROC: TSyncVlProc(sr.Proc)(PVList(sr.Param)^);
          FF_NON_OBJ_VLIST_PROC: TSyncVlNonObjectProc(TMethod(sr.Proc).Code)(PVList(sr.Param)^);
          FF_VAR_PROC: TSyncVarProc(sr.Proc)(sr.VarValue);
          FF_NON_OBJ_VAR_PROC: TSyncVarNonObjectProc(TMethod(sr.Proc).Code)(sr.VarValue);
          FF_VAR_FUNC: sr.VarValue := TSyncVarFunc(sr.Proc)(sr.VarValue);
          FF_NON_OBJ_VAR_FUNC: sr.VarValue := TSyncVarNonObjectFunc(TMethod(sr.Proc).Code)(sr.VarValue);
          else
            raise Exception.Create('unsuppoted sync param/ret combination');
        end;
      except
        if isDeferred then
          raise
        else
        begin
          {$IFDEF D6UP}
          sr.Xcpt := AcquireExceptionObject
          {$ELSE}
          if RaiseList <> nil then
          begin
            sr.Xcpt := PRaiseFrame(RaiseList)^.ExceptObject;
            PRaiseFrame(RaiseList)^.ExceptObject := nil;
          end
          else
            raise;
          {$ENDIF}
        end;
      end
    finally
      if isDeferred then
      begin
        LastHandledSyncRecID := sr.ID;
        Dispose(sr);
      end;
    end;
  end;

  result := 0;
end;

var
  HandlerWindowClass: TWndClass = (
    style: 0;
    lpfnWndProc: @HandlerWndProc;
    cbClsExtra: 0;
    cbWndExtra: 0;
    hInstance: 0;
    hIcon: 0;
    hCursor: 0;
    hbrBackground: 0;
    lpszMenuName: nil;
    lpszClassName: 'TSyncFuncHandlerWindow');

procedure CreateHandlerWindow;
var
  TempClass: TWndClass;
  ClassRegistered: Boolean;
begin
  HandlerWindowClass.hInstance := HInstance;
  ClassRegistered := GetClassInfo(HInstance, HandlerWindowClass.lpszClassName, TempClass);
  if not ClassRegistered or (TempClass.lpfnWndProc <> @HandlerWndProc) then
  begin
    if ClassRegistered then
      Windows.UnregisterClass(HandlerWindowClass.lpszClassName, HInstance);
    Windows.RegisterClass(HandlerWindowClass);
  end;
  fHandlerWindow := CreateWindow(HandlerWindowClass.lpszClassName, '', 0, 0, 0, 0,
{$WARNINGS OFF} // to prevent D2k7 warning about violation constant bounds
    HWND_MESSAGE,
{$WARNINGS ON}
    0, 0, HInstance, nil);
  if fHandlerWindow = 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('Unable to create handler window: ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
end;
```

Ошибка выходит на эту строчку в конце:

```
raise Exception.Create('Unable to create handler window: ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
```

Эту программу переводил с Delphi 7 на Delphi 10.2!

Comment: А без отладчика? Есть подозрение, что в режиме отладки это нормальное поведение. Можно посмотреть в IDE настройки по исключениям при отладке.

Comment: @ValertonGT А какую ошибку это исключение выводит? Меня интересует GetLastError что содержит. По логике программы исключение возникнет если окно не удалось создать, вот GetLastError может прояснить причину ошибки создания окна. Если исключение нигде не ловится и не выводится его сообщение, тогда можете в последнем if перед исключением добавить вывод на экран или в консоль и посмотреть что там за код ошибки.

Comment: [Здравствуйте, я ошибка 217 и я вам ничего не скажу](https://habrahabr.ru/post/209902/)

Comment: Проверьте параметры передаваемые в функцию `SetTimer`, скорее всего ломается именно в этом месте.

Comment: я для отладки мутных ошибок комменчу код, пока ошибка не исчезнет.. Если эту строку закомментить, то ошибка появится или нет? Просто много ошибки вылазят позже, столкнувшись с порушенной памятью или другим глюком.